# Why not modify a shuttle craft?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

In the series finale, Burnham creates a Red Angel suit to go through the worm hole. Why not modify a shuttle craft? It already has weapons, so you don't need that many ships to escort you. With a Red Angel suit, Control knows who to look for, but with a shuttle craft, you can possibly hide among other craft.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no direct statement in the show to explain it, or I may have missed it in the atrocious directing and hyper-accelerated dialog but to be fair of all the holes the last episodes are filled with this is probably the only one that can be easily hand-waved away with a bit of logic.

Discovery crew have the schematics of a fully functioning suit, and decided that the best strategy was to find themselves short on time and in the middle of a battle; at that point it goes without saying that 3D printing the suit is a safe bet: adapting the unknown technology to a shuttle will take time and will require some testing, no matter how little. I mean, it's a circuit of sort, designed to be merged into a suit containing a human being and to navigate that mass across time. You can't just glue it to a shuttle and hope it works immediately.

Comment: There was no guarantee that the suit would have worked. The only reason it worked is because the writers said it would, and as it turns out she was the red angel that set the signals. Meh, the answer is still good enough.

Comment: Why wouldn't the suit work? There's already a working prototype and they have the exact specs.

Comment: @BrianOrtiz - The suit works because as I stated the writers wanted it to work, if they wanted it to fail they would have come up with some reason for it to happen. Remember, we find it Burnham was the Red Angel in all those other moments, so she had to have the suit. To me anyways, a shuttle craft seemed easier.

Comment: @BrianOrtiz Even with exact specs, it’s possible to make mistakes during construction, especially the sort of frantic construction that we’re shown during the episode.

Comment: @Joe - Exactly, remember we were shown all the people that were helping during construction and because of how frantic it was they were making mistakes? Unless they have QA off screen, a mistake could have slipped by, but because the writers wanted it to be a success, it worked.

Comment: Whipping together a last minute engineering solution to save the day is a Star Trek staple. I don't see the problem.

Comment: @BrianOrtiz - I think we're losing sight of the original question :D. I still think a shuttle craft would have been easier to work with, and both a SC and the Red Angel suit had to be tested before using it, but they either didn't do it, or didn't show it.

Comment: @nsoline the Red Angel suit is absolutely not tested before being used by Michael, it is still being constructed on the way to the shuttle bay that she launches from.